# Accessing Calculated Value in Text Area Spotfire

Tags: python, spotfire

I am trying to access a calculated value sitting in a text area with the API. My python skills are not that good, but I believe I am pretty close, and that this will probably be an easy question for someone more experienced. I have looked around a good bit and haven't found a solution.

So far this is what I have:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import Miniatures

val1 = Miniatures.CalculatedValueMiniatureVisualizationDetails.Value


print val1
```

This gives me the following:

property# Value on CalculatedValueMiniatureVisualizationDetails>.

The real question is how do I extract the value from this property?

Thanks,

Jamey

Comment: Are you trying to use this value within the analysis? Perhaps as part of an expression?

Comment: I am trying to get the value so I can apply some logic. I have two calculated values in a text area that I want to compare the values then change the background color with jQuery. Something like if val1>val2 then green else red. Here val1 and cal2 reference the calculated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up ditching this way and solved this problem by using jQuery:

I ended up figuring this one out. Here is the html:

```
<body >
<div id = wrapper>
<div id = thisyear><SpotfireControl id="d644de4c97c440fbb78c561f190e5a47" />   </div>

<div id = lastyear ><SpotfireControl id="f98415c74eb34cedbab057f763788bc6" /></div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the jQuery that gets this done:

```
setInterval(function() {
   var thisyearval = parseInt($("#thisyear").text(),10)
   var lastyearval = parseInt($("#lastyear").text(),10)


   if (thisyearval > lastyearval){
      $("#wrapper").css("background-color", "#009900")
   } else{$("#wrapper").css("background-color", "#FF0000")}
}, 500);
```

It turns out that spotfire doesnt support the change function in jQuery, so I used setInterval() to essentially call the function over and over.

Hopefully this will help someone else out too.